# dbjdns and nsupdate inter-compatibility?

Tags: domain-name-system, tinydns

Anyone aware if tinydns (dbjdns) and nsupdate work together and how to set this up?

I can't find any documentation on the subject and would really love to use tinydns over bind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`tinydns`](http://cr.yp.to/djbdns/tinydns.html) does not support the [dynamic updates](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2136) DNS extension, which is what the `nsupdate` client application implements.

In general the djbdns software has not received much attention for a long time (the last actual release was made in 2001), even though there are forks as well as separate patches that fix some bugs and add some much needed functionality it's not in what I would consider a great state overall.

Comment: Thanks. Although I somewhat disagree on the state of tinydns. We used it at my old company for about 45,000 records that were hammered none stop by hundreds of thousands of concurrent users and it rocked it hard. We also had puppet and scripts to update the zone file dynamically and pull old/new hosts in and out. Give here another chance sometime! Also thanks for the answer!